# Is it possible to define a container and the background-color over the whole viewport in a single html element?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a single page with different sections. Each section contains a container with text content. But each section should have a different background-color like [here](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/qgxCF).
So far two elements are necessary to set the background color and span the container for a grid:

```
<section class="about">
    <div class="container"></div>
</section>
<section class="contact">
    <div class="container"></div>
</section>
```

To colorize each section across the whole viewport i've used the `.about` and `.contact` classes on the section elements, the container is spanned by the `.container` class within the scope of the included div elements.

```
.container {
    width:88%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.about {
    background-color:red;
}
.contact {
    background-color:green;
}
```

But would it be possible to apply the background-color AND the container in just one single element? That only the section elements would be necessary and not the divs anymore like

```
<section class="about container"></section>
<section class="contact container"></section>
```

Best regards Ralf

Comment: You could use a padding-left and padding-right of 11%, but using two divs is a better solution.

Comment: @VictorIn why have un-needed divs? That's not very semantic. Much better to present stylized sections. Keep in mind that older browsers are going to frown at the section element, and you're going to need a JS library like modernizr to make them be ok with HTML5 tags.

Comment: Defining the section as `display: block` makes it work in older browsers, you don't need js. ||| Because only a div will work like you want it. Paddings will work with simple texts, but as soon as you'll have more complex child-elements you will need a lot of work-around css to position everything correctly. So the question is: Is a lot of additional css worth the small semantic enhancement?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 6%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.about {
    background-color:red;
}
.contact {
    background-color:green;
}
```

and your HTML as you've specified:

```
<section class="about container"></section>
<section class="contact container"></section>
```

Comment: Yes the end result looks what i was looking for, but it has one downside. It only works in a certain breakpoint ranges. e.g. from 500px to 850px. But in the case i reach the max-width and dont want to grow the container even more i run into the initial problem again. The width remains static and you are unable to handle things with the padding. It is only possible with the margin property but that leads to the case that only the container has the assigned background-color - the margin area remains white: http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/LmFcj

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for since it still consists of two elements but I see no reason to omit the second element. As for semantics, in my opinion it makes sense to put an article in each section that would act as the "container" in this case.

```
section {
 width: 100%;
}

.about {
 background-color: red;
}

.contact {
 background-color: blue;
}

article {
 width: 88%;
}



<section class="about">
 <article></article>
</section>
<section class="contact">
 <article></article>
</section>
```